# Como quitar flecha a un Select

Tags: php, css, select

Estoy trabajando con PHP, tengo un formulario que tiene algunos Select. Mi problema es que quisiera eliminar la flecha que traen todos los Select por defecto, he intentado en mi hoja CSS aplicar algunos estilos que busque y deberían funcionar pero no me resulto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MI SELECT

```
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <select class="form-control" name="carrera" id="carrera" required>
             <option value="">Selecciona una Carrera</option>
              <?php  foreach ($carr as $c): ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $c->id ?>">
              <?php echo $c->nombre_carr ?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
         </div>
```

Mi codigo CSS para el select

```
 select { 
 -moz-appearance: none; 
  text-indent: 0.01px; 
  text-overflow: ''; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu CSS, debes agregar a tu etiqueta `select` las siguientes propiedades:

```
 select {
 -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
  color:black;
  background: white;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 -ms-appearance:none;
 -o-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
 }
```

Con estas propiedades eliminas todo el diseño del `select` que se muestra por defecto, es por eso que también se le deberá aplicar un `background` y `color` para que no se pierda el texto del select.

Aquí tengo un [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/ZErgvOY) para que lo puedas visualizar mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio